# Should we use .prototype instead of current instanciation method?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

In a JavaScript code, we currently create a lot of objects using Method1 (see code). Would it be better to use Method2? (using .prototype) What would the benefits be? (Espescially interested in execution speed and memory usage.)

```
   var exampleObjectFunction1 = function(){ alert(this.exampleProperty1);};
   var exampleObjectFunction2 = function(){ this.myFunction1(); };
   var exeampleProperties = {
       exampleProperty1: 'example',
        exampleProperty2: 'example',
    };

   //Method1: Current instanciation method
   function exampleObject1(properties) {
       this.exampleProperty1 = properties.property1;
       this.examplePropertyX = properties.propertyX;
       this.exampleObjectFunction1 = exampleObjectFunction1;
       this.exampleObjectFunction2 = exampleObjectFunction2;
   };
   var exampleObject1 = new exampleObject(properties);

   //Method2: Using prototype (better?)
   function exampleObject2(properties) {
       this.exampleProperty1 = properties.property1;
       this.examplePropertyX = properties.propertyX;
   };
   exampleObject2.prototype.exampleObjectFunction1 = exampleObjectFunction1;
   exampleObject2.prototype.exampleObjectFunction2 = exampleObjectFunction2;

   var exampleObject2 = new exampleObject2(properties);
```

Edit: I see a lot of "constructor vs prototype" comparisons. But the "constructor" codes there usually redefine the functions inside the constructor while I pre-define them in re-usable variable. I think that this is a different scheme, though I am not quite sure if it's closer to "prototype" or to "constructor".

Comment: You're not going to have multiple redundant implementations of the same function, but multiple redundant references to the same functions. The code is also more complicated, since you define and assign the functions in two steps, instead of just once on `exampleObject1.prototype`, which `exampleObject2` could inherit for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you create 1000 objects of exampleObject1 and 1000 objects of exampleObject2.

If you want to override exampleFunction1 for all exampleObject1 objects, you have to iterate through all your objects and change it.

If you want to do it for all exampleObject2 objects, you just change it's prototype in one place.

So, from the point of code extensibility is using of prototype better choice.

Comment: What about memory usage ? I thing you mentionned if in a previous version of you answer but removed it ?Though it seems to match "deceze" comments on original post.

Comment: Yes I removed it because I have noticed that you are not creating functions in constructor. You have only a lot of references to the same function as @deceze mentioned. In this case, using of prototype should be 'slightly' better from the point of memory usage. But I have never saw any benchmark :)